# Como Saber se o Form que é filho de um TPanel está aberto

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Opa!
Tenho uma duvida. Como saber se uma form atribuído como filho de uma `TPanel` está abeto?
Meu form está sendo criado assim:

```
if not(Assigned(Form2)) then
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(self);
  Form2.Parent := Panel1;
  Form2.Show;
end;
```

O intuito é evitar Criar outra instancia do mesmo form. Já tentei assim, `if not(Assigned(Form2)) then` e sempre fala que ela não está `Assigned` e cria outro form.

Fonte da Unit1

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2; 

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not(Assigned(Form2)) then
  begin
    Form2 := TForm2.Create(self);
    Form2.Parent := Panel1;
    Form2.Show;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Fonte do Unit2:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit1;    

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

end.
```

O Fonte a Unit1 só muda que o `Button` da abre a Unit2
 
O `FormStle` tanto do *Form2* como *Form1* está setado com `fsNormal`.

Comment: Pode mostrar a criação da classe `TForm2` ?

Comment: A criação é padrão do Delphi não modifiquei nada

Comment: `Form2` é uma variável publica ou local?

Comment: Velho eu fui em New - VCL Application - Delphi o que gerou  a Unit1. Depois fui em New - VCl Form - Delphi o que gerou a Unit2, coloquei os dois Buttons não crie nada alen das duas procedure. tudo ai foi padrão do Delphi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressione Alt+P+V exclua o formulário que ele incluí automaticamente, deve estar algo como: `Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);`

Este teste lógico:

`if not(Assigned(Form2)) then`

Na documentação explica que `Assigned`pode não representar o estado de existência do objeto, se é = `nil`.

O correto é testar se ele é = ou diferente <> `nil`

`if Form2 = nil then`

Agora, o que há de fato errado é a manipulação da classe, você esta usando `Form2` diretamente da classe `TForm2`. *Funciona, mas não esta certo.*

O correto é você declarar uma variável ali no `{ Private declarations }` do tipo `TForm2` e a partir deste controlar sua existência.

```
if vForm = nil then
begin
  vForm := TForm2.Create(Self);
  vForm .Parent := Panel1;   
end;

vForm .Show;
```

Comment: Eu vou declarar TForm2 no Private da Unit1?

Comment: No private do unit1 você declara `vForm: TForm2;`

Comment: Então para cada Formulário terá uma Variável?

Comment: @EduMendonça Tem que ser.